# What could cause intermittent function in outlets?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I have some outlets and switches that aren't working. Periodically they will start working again out of the blue.

The power company has been out and checked their side of things. Both legs are working.

I've switched around multiple outlets to determine that its not a faulty breaker.

Any ideas what else it could be?

Comment: Are the outlets and switches that are not working all on one or two breakers or are they on many different breakers?

Comment: Shut off all your 240V breakers (pump, water heater, A/C, range etc.)  Do the circuits go stone dead at this point?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that they are working intermittently means a wire connection is loose somewhere.  This means there could be arcing which is a fire hazard.  Narrow it down to the circuit that those outlets and switches are on.  Chances are they are all on one circuit.  The easiest thing to do would be shut off power to the circuit, open the outlets for each switch and receptacle, verify power is off at each device, and check connections.  That includes the screw terminals and any splices made.  Worst case is if there are buried splices or an animal chewed wires, a nail went through wires, etc.  Hopefully it's in one of the junction boxes that you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Intermittently working as a loose connection someplace. If the power goes to your light first and then down to the receptacles in the car is probably behind an overhead light. On older homes everything was tied together behind the light fixtures.
The power being intermittent is most likely a loose connection on a neutral wire so check every single outlet and if its wire under a crawl space go there and look at the wiring.
Something intermittent like that after you’ve gone through all these situations really sounds to me like a chewing of the wires

Comment: This doesn't add much to the other answer that's here, and I'm confused by the reference to "receptacles in the car". What car?